# Effective Production Issue Reporting

Tags: google-app-engine

I have several billed apps, one of which suddenly started getting latencies ten times normal - even for static resources). Other apps were unaffected, so it wasn't a general problem. No code changes, no errors, so I'm fairly sure it is not a code snafu. Updated app.yaml and incremented default version - no change. Problem happens on several instances. This results in a badly degraded experience for my customers.

But when I come to report this to Google, my only option seems to be the group. Two years ago when I had a similar problem, there was a "Report production issue" button in the console. My first message to the group was deleted (perhaps because I included an app ID?) and my next one was unanswered. The issue is still ongoing, which makes me think it has been ignored.

I love Appengine, and advocate for it strongly. But when things go bad, it turns very ugly. There is definitely something going wrong that the Appengine team should know about, but there seems no way to report this.

Comment: The latency stopped very shortly after I made this post, and another one on the appengine group. Not sure if it was related because I didn't identify the app ID in either post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does have a place where you can and should [Report Production Issues](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue)  Keep in mind that while Google reads those, they do not respond individually.

Refer to [Where to file AppEngine Issues](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3) for the full list of where to report the following:

- Billing Issues
- Defects
- Feature Requests
- Production Issues

Also, you should file for a credit (I mean I assume having to provide you credit would push them towards resolving the issue right!) if you are seeing:

- HTTP Request: INTERNAL_SERVING_ERROR
- Datastore api: INTERNAL_ERROR, TIMEOUT, BIGTABLE_ERROR,
  COMMITTED_BUT_STILL_APPLYING, TRY_ALTERNATE_BACKEND

For Bronze, [file for SLA credit here](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_sla)
For Silver and up use the link on the Bronze page to create a support ticket.

General billing inquires are here: [billing inquires are here](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing?rd=1%20general%20billing%20inquires)

Comment: Thank you. I did not find this despite a lot of searching last night.